# How would I exclude columns when retrieving data from a Kendo grid?

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui

I am pulling all data from a Kendo grid using this call in Javascript:

```
var data = JSON.stringify($(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data())
```

It returns all of the properties in the C# class for these records.  There are three properties which I did not show in the Kendo presentation, but they are being returned to this call (and subsequently being sent along to an Export to CSV call).

How can I exclude these columns from this data call?

EDIT:

Following @DontVoteMeDown 's example, I tried to make a function out of this:

```
            function removeKeys(data) {
            let excludedKeys = ['InvoiceId', 'IsOk', 'ErrorMessage'],
                newData = data.map((item) => {
                    let newObj = {};

                    Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
                        if (excludedKeys.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                            newObj[key] = item[key];
                        }
                    });

                    return newObj;
                });
        }
```

However, in the Console debugger, I am getting an error.

When I call the sequence as this, I get an undefined 'data':

```
    var tableData = $(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

    var dataChop = removeKeys(tableData);

    var data = JSON.stringify(dataChop);
```

When I call in this sequence, I get an error that 'data.map is not a function':

```
    var tableData = $(".k-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data();

    var dataFull = JSON.stringify(tableData);

    var data = removeKeys(dataFull);
```

How should I call this mapping function?

Comment: `dataSource.data()` returns an iterable on which you can apply a `map`. Just create a map function that returns an object excluding the fileds you want to exclude.

Comment: excellent.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of what @ZorgoZ proposed:

```js
let data = [{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3
}, {
  a: 4,
  b: 5,
  c: 6
}];

let excludedKeys = ['c'],
    newData = data.map((item) => {
      let newObj = {};
          
      Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
          if (excludedKeys.indexOf(key) == -1) {
              newObj[key] = item[key];
          }
      });
   
      return newObj;
   });
   
console.log(newData);
```

Being *data* your `dataSource.data()`.

Comment: thank you.  Please see my edit for a request on how to implement; I am getting errors.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger the first way you've tried should work. The other don't, because you can run `map` in a string, and `JSON.stringify()` returns a string. Check in your first attemp if `tableData` is an array indeed.

Comment: It is an array, of my Invoice objects.  What's interesting too, is that it has every property of Invoice, plus about 10 other properties of the Kendo grid.  Ultimately the CSV Export function is only showing the Invoice fields (all of them unfortunately)

Comment: @JasonPSallinger I got it to work [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/iYojezul). But yes, the data source item objects has lots of kendo's properties on it.